# My magento site can't sent email to the customer

Tags: magento

Does anyone know why Magento 1.4 fails to send email notifications for a new order and  account activation ? 
 when I submit the Contact us form it gives the below error.

`Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later`Any idea/suggestion on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: i don't know how to inspect the error logs and where its in?

Comment: guess you have to learn then cause no body else will not do it for you

Answer (score 1):

More info please. Is this on a Linux box, Windows, etc... Also check the php configuration SMTP settings. Like any php app, email is handed off to the host system, or to server designated in php.ini. Do you have a known working SMTP server to access?

Comment: it's on Linux. how to check php configuration SMTP settings.

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php for the SMTP setting in the php.ini. Especailly the _sendmail_path_ setting

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to check is whether email communication is disabled in the admin panel.